# Cannot find 'ConfigurationIntent' in scope error

Tags: ios, xcode, widgetkit

Adding a Widget Extension target to a new or existing iOS project leads to a bogus error when building the project: `Cannot find 'ConfigurationIntent' in scope`. Cleaning DerivedData / project does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that if you have a `Class Prefix` assigned to your xcode project document settings, xcode will silently add the prefix to the auto-built configuration intent class but this isn't obvious because the configuration itself does not contain a prefix.

In my case I had a prefix `TDD`. I spotted the file TDDConfigurationIntent.swift in the build folder. The solution is to either rename the configuration intent manually OR remove the class prefix in project document settings.